# Error: use of deleted function for overloaded template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying template specialization,  but cannot determine the reason why a `char const * const` cannot be resolved below (despite being a *valid* type).

```cpp
template <typename A, typename B> B foo (A) = delete;

template <> void foo (char *) {}
template <> void foo (char const * const) {}

int main () {
    { // types OK
        char const * const a = nullptr;
        char * b = nullptr;
    }

    char * data;
    foo<char *, void>(data); // OK
    foo<char const * const, void>(data); // ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

The error

```
error: use of deleted function ‘B foo(A) [with A = const char* const; B = void]’
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I expect that the last `const` (the one that applies to the pointer, and not the pointed-to object) is what's causing the problem. `void foo(char const * const) {}` is a function taking a `char const *`, and incidentally it won't change the value of that pointer in the body of the function.  I suspect `foo<char const *, void>(data);` would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that top-level `const` qualifier is ignored for parameter type, so the specialization of

```
template <> void foo (char const * const) {}
```

is just same as

```
template <> void foo (char const *) {}
```

which is a specialized version for `foo<char const *, void>`, not `foo<char const * const, void>` (as you expected).

As the workaround you can make the invocation and the specialization match, e.g. change the specialization explicitly to

```
template <> void foo<char const * const, void> (char const * const) {}
```

or change the invocation to

```
foo<char const *, void>(data);
```

Comment: Why is the toplevel `const ` qualifier ignored when only the parameter types are given? I'm wondering why this rule would make sense.

Comment: @lubgr It only makes sense for the implementation, i.e. the `const` parameter can't be changed inside the function. But from the viewpoint of the caller, it doesn't make any difference. The argument is copied to the parameter, the caller doesn't care it's `const` or not. So we can't define two function like `void foo(int);` and `void foo(const int)` at the same time; they're considered to be the same signature.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.